# Woocommerce, show only products with two specific categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

In Woocommerce, I'm trying to filter the products on my shop page and keep only the products belonging to two specific categories.

To give a better idea of what I'm trying to do, I am developing a kids clothing shop and we have a form on one page where the user selects the age and the gender of their kids. So when they submit the form, they are taken to the product page where the only clothing items displayed are the ones corresponding to both the age and gender selected earlier.

For example, if I select "Male" and "3 months old", the only products I want on the page are the ones belonging to both the "male" tag and "3-months" tags.

Basically an "AND" filter on product categories.

All I can do right now is get every product who have one of the two tags. So for "Male" and "3 months old", the products page shows all clothes with the male tag, regardless of the age and all the clothes with the 3 months old tag, regardless of the gender

Comment: Try look here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/278392

Answer (score 0):

To filter products by multiple categories using an "AND" operation in WooCommerce, you need to customize the query and construct the shop page URL appropriately.

Modify the Shop Page URL:
Construct the URL to accept multiple category parameters by **appending & instead of repeating category=.**

**Example URL:** `/shop/?category=cat1,cat2`

Customize the Query:
Intercept the query on the shop page and modify it to consider all selected categories as mandatory (an "AND" operation).

Here's a PHP code snippet you can use:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_product_query');

function custom_product_query($q){
    if (isset($_GET['category']) && !empty($_GET['category'])) {
        $categories = explode(',', $_GET['category']);
        $tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
        foreach ($categories as $category_slug) {
            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $category_slug,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            );
        }
        $q->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
    }
}
```

This code modifies the WooCommerce product query to enforce an "AND" operation for the selected categories. It constructs a tax_query array where all category terms are included with the relation set to 'AND'.

After adding this code, you should be able to construct a URL like `/shop/?category=cat1,cat2` where products belong to both "cat1" and "cat2" categories. Adjust the category slugs according to your actual category names.